# Replace lambda with method reference containing new keyword

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

```
List<Employee> empListObjDeepCopy = empListRef.stream().map(inv -> new Employee(inv)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How to replace this `(inv -> new Employee(inv))` lambda with Method reference.

Full Code reference:

```
package org.learn.copy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class DeepCopy {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setName("Hello");
        emp.setRollNumber("12345");

        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.setName("Hi");
        emp1.setRollNumber("123456");

        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();
        empList.add(emp);
        empList.add(emp1);

        List<Employee> empListRef = empList;

        System.out.println("empList Obj: "+empList.get(0).getName());
        System.out.println("empListRef Obj: "+empListRef.get(0).getName());

        List<Employee> empListObjDeepCopy = empListRef.stream().map(inv -> new Employee(inv)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        empListObjDeepCopy.get(0).setName("Hi");

        System.out.println("empList Obj: "+empList.get(0).getName());
        System.out.println("empListRef Obj: "+empListRef.get(0).getName());
        System.out.println("empListObjDeepCopy Obj: "+empListObjDeepCopy.get(0).getName());
    }
}

class Employee {
    private String name; 
    private String rollNumber;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getRollNumber() {
        return rollNumber;
    }
    public void setRollNumber(String rollNumber) {
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
    }
    public Employee(Employee employee) {
        this.name = employee.name;
        this.rollNumber = employee.rollNumber;
    }
    public Employee() {
        super();
    }   
}
```

Comment: `map(Employee::new)`

Comment: change to `List<Employee> empListObjDeepCopy = empListRef.stream().map(Employee::new).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Thanks, It worked.

Comment: How this question is not clear or useful. It is common doubt that if there are multiple constructors then whether (Employee::new) will work or not. I tried this but it wasn't working, that's why I asked the question. Please, do care to provide the explanation if you downvote.

Comment: One important finding, I just needed to share. It was not working earlier as I have given the following constructor:
public Employee(String name, String rollNumber){
  this.name = name;
  this.rollNumber = rollNumber;  
 }
Above explained method reference only works if the constructor with Employee object as formal argument is present.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.map(Employee::new)` is ambiguous because you have two constructors in your `Employee` class. Try to leave only one.

Comment: It's not ambiguous. It will select the correct constructor depending on the context.